# Output of the ps command and understanding the flags

Tags: bash, shell, java, ps

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using bash.

I tried running the ps command from a Java program using the Runtime and got some unexpected output.

Upon closer inspection I realized that it was the output of:

```
ps --deselect
```

Which leads me to believe that ps executes with some default flags enabled

When I just type

```
ps
```

in the command line.

What are these flags? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: What is the output of `alias ps`?

Comment: Note that `--deselect` is the same as `-N`

Comment: empty. the output of alis ps is empty.

Comment: Have you tried "man ps"?

Comment: I tried my best to understand it, but to no avail :( .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps` honours an environment variable called `PS_PERSONALITY` when choosing how to display its results (documented in the man page). The values I have in my man page are:

```
PERSONALITY
   390        like the OS/390 OpenEdition ps
   aix        like AIX ps
   bsd        like FreeBSD ps (totally non-standard)
   compaq     like Digital Unix ps
   debian     like the old Debian ps
   digital    like Tru64 (was Digital Unix, was OSF/1) ps
   gnu        like the old Debian ps
   hp         like HP-UX ps
   hpux       like HP-UX ps
   irix       like Irix ps
   linux      ***** recommended *****
   old        like the original Linux ps (totally non-standard)
   os390      like OS/390 Open Edition ps
   posix      standard
   s390       like OS/390 Open Edition ps
   sco        like SCO ps
   sgi        like Irix ps
   solaris2   like Solaris 2+ (SunOS 5) ps
   sunos4     like SunOS 4 (Solaris 1) ps (totally non-standard)
   svr4       standard
   sysv       standard
   tru64      like Tru64 (was Digital Unix, was OSF/1) ps
   unix       standard
   unix95     standard
   unix98     standard
```

You may want to try them all :-), using

```
PS_PERSONALITY=digital ps
```

Most likely, the value of the environment variable `PS_PERSONALITY` is different (or maybe absent) when you execute `ps` from within a program, compared to when you run it in your interactive shell (likely with custom set-up in `.bashrc` and the like).